# Firebase Authentication : is there any limits in sign in with google options

Tags: firebase-authentication

is there any limits on firebase Authentication with google sign in. if yes how many gmail's can i authenticate per day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no documented limit to how many people can sign in to Firebase with Google sign-in credentials. While there may be a limit to protect against abuse, it is not something you should usually worry about.

Btw: Google sign-in credentials are not limited to gmail users, as you can create a Google account based on any email address.